# Hazelcast - Owner node and backup node are the same

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast 3.6 to clustering some locks and I'm getting the following error:

```
2016-02-15 08:30:56,212{GMT} ERROR c.h.c.l.o.UnlockIfLeaseExpiredOperation:[10.70.167.253]:6701 [dev] [3.6] Normally shouldn't happen! Owner node and backup node are the same! Partition [204]{
    0:Address[10.70.167.254]:6701
    1:Address[10.70.167.253]:6701
    2:Address[10.70.167.252]:6701
    3:Address[10.70.167.251]:6701
    4:Address[10.70.167.255]:6701
}java.lang.IllegalStateException: Normally shouldn't happen! Owner node and backup node are the same! Partition [204]{
    0:Address[10.70.167.254]:6701
    1:Address[10.70.167.253]:6701
    2:Address[10.70.167.252]:6701
    3:Address[10.70.167.251]:6701
    4:Address[10.70.167.255]:6701
}
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.assertNoBackupOnPrimaryMember(OperationBackupHandler.java:262) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendSingleBackup(OperationBackupHandler.java:182) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.makeBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:159) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.backup(OperationBackupHandler.java:78) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendBackup(OperationRunnerImpl.java:262) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:245) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:173) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processOperation(OperationThread.java:198) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:132) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:124) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:99) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]

2016-02-15 08:30:56,212{GMT} WARN  c.h.c.l.LockEvictionProcessor:[10.70.167.253]:6701 [dev] [3.6] Normally shouldn't happen! Owner node and backup node are the same! Partition [204]{
    0:Address[10.70.167.254]:6701
    1:Address[10.70.167.253]:6701
    2:Address[10.70.167.252]:6701
    3:Address[10.70.167.251]:6701
    4:Address[10.70.167.255]:6701
}java.lang.IllegalStateException: Normally shouldn't happen! Owner node and backup node are the same! Partition [204]{
    0:Address[10.70.167.254]:6701
    1:Address[10.70.167.253]:6701
    2:Address[10.70.167.252]:6701
    3:Address[10.70.167.251]:6701
    4:Address[10.70.167.255]:6701
}
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.assertNoBackupOnPrimaryMember(OperationBackupHandler.java:262) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendSingleBackup(OperationBackupHandler.java:182) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.makeBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:159) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.backup(OperationBackupHandler.java:78) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendBackup(OperationRunnerImpl.java:262) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:245) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:173) ~[hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processOperation(OperationThread.java:198) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:132) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:124) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:99) [hazelcast-3.6.jar:3.6]
```

I'm used the version 3.5.X in other projects and I didn't had this problem. I'm not finding much info about this error, I need to change some settings for this version of Hazelcast?

Comment: Hi, this is a known issue in Hazelcast 3.6. You can ignore it. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/7405 for details.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by Jaromir's comment, it was a known problem and is fixed in 3.6.1, please consider updating if you haven't updated already (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/7405)